# Performance penalty for using C++ vector instead of C array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, std

Is there a performance penalty for working with a vector from the standard library in C++ instead of arrays in C?

Comment: suggest your benchmark your precise situation.

Comment: @Wheat, Couldn't agree more with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's not (provided you compile with optimization so inlining can happen), provided you mean dynamically sized C "arrays" obtained with malloc.

Fixed-sized arrays in C will have the slight advantage that their address is fixed after linking (if global), or that they live directly on the stack rather than indirectly through a pointer to somewhere on the heap.  I do believe there is still no performance difference; constant base addresses aren't faster than variable ones; both get loaded into a CPU register.

Comment: This answer is WRONG!

Answer (score 1):

The only real difference is that accesses with std::vector go through trivial functions.  So long as you're using an appropriate optimization level such that those function calls get inlined, they'll be the same.